# Web History/Connection Logger

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm thinking of writing an application that when running keeps track of all the websites I visit and connections I make. 
Basically like a browser history, but I want to do it in a way that utilizes network concepts.

I only have a rudimentary understanding of Http, but would I be able to listen in on  Http get requests from the browser and automatically pull information whenever a request is made? If anyone can give me a suggestion or outline of how this can be done, so I can research on implementing it, it would be very helpful! I'm thinking of implementing it in python, and my operating system is Ubuntu

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by implementing a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy).

In your case, basically, an agent that sits between your browser and internet. The proxy receive the request from the client, then, send it to the remote server, the remote server may reply to you and you'll have to send the server response back to the client.

To retrieve the informations you are wanting, reading the [Http rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) will be helpful.

Comment: Awesome dude. This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to start learning about this and see if I can implement this. Thanks!